# Checking "Supports Running without iOS App Installation" on Watch App disables WCSession from operating

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, wcsession, watchos-6

I checked "Supports Running without iOS App Installation" on a build I submitted to the app store (so that I could get a location permission alert on the watch), however I am noticing that because of this my WCSession calls to the iPhone when session is active are not firing (Xcode Console says that companion app is not detected).  I believe this is a bug as we should have the option to use WCSession for messaging back and forth even and provide an alternative when not available (Filed a Feedback #  FB7928809).  At this point I need to get my WCSession back but Xcode won't let me upload a version with it unchecked since I already have a release version with "Supports Running Without iOS App Installation in the store."  What can I do to get WCSession operation back?

Answer (score 0):

This must be an intermittent issue because in testing today WCSession was working on both devices.